# Insert Word Headings in ListBox including numbers with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, listbox, userform

Currently I use VBA to create headlines at a certain level. For this I use the following code:

```
Private Sub InsertButton_Click()

'Insert Title
With Word.Selection
.TypeText Text:=FeatureBox.Text & " " & "-" & " " & ComponentBox.Text & " " & "-" & " " & TitleBox.Text
.Font.size = 12
.Font name = "Calibri"
.Font.Bold = True
.style = wdStyleHeading3
.type paragraph

End With

End Sub
```

I would like to automatically insert each heading on level 3 into a Multicolumn ListBox. Copying the text is less of a problem, but I would like to insert the automatically generated heading number into the ListBox as well. As an additional function I would like to jump to the element selected in the ListBox by double clicking.

Is this even possible? I would be very grateful for your help.

Many thanks and best regards

Ben

Comment: Though I can't find it in the (poor) VB2008 documentation, the list box control has a double click event.

Comment: Yes thought so, I think this is the lesser problem :D

Comment: If you are setting the style to Heading 3 then setting font properties is pointless. They will be overridden by the style.